# How can I truncate milliseconds to 2 most significant decimals in strftime()

Tags: python, strftime

I have a datetime object that is printed with:

```py
from datetime import datetime

ts = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strip()
print('TS: {}'.format(ts))

# "2020-12-03 02:13:27.823467"
```

However, I only want the first 2 digits of the *milliseconds* to be shown, like this: `2020-12-03 02:13:27.82`. Using "`%.2f`" didn't work, and perhaps there's another *time* function more suitable?

**What is the best way to do this without introducing (possibly laggy) regex string manipulations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like the following?

```
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now()
ts = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + '.{:02d}'.format(round(now.microsecond, -4))[:3]
print('TS: {}'.format(ts))
# TS: 2020-12-03 01:22:01.86
```

---

**EDIT**

Perhaps a better parametrized solution would be:

```
import datetime


def largest_digits(value, num_digits=2, max_digits=6):
    discard_digits = num_digits - max_digits 
    base = 10 ** -discard_digits
    return f'{round(value, discard_digits) // base:02d}'


now = datetime.datetime.now()
ts = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + '.' + largest_digits(now.microsecond, 2)
print('TS: {}'.format(ts))
# TS: 2020-12-03 01:22:01.86
```

Comment: Good one! Thank you. I ended up needing 3 decimals after all, so I used: `'{:03d}'.format(round(t0.microsecond, -2))[:3]`.

Comment: Not the code I am most the proud of, since it is not well parametrized. But your values seems off: `round(value, digit)` should be with `digit==3` for 3 decimals

Answer (score 0):

Aaahi, the answer was trivial! Use string selection.

```py
ts = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strip()[:-4]
```

Comment: careful with that. It may be fine in this case, but if python didn't output zeros on even values, you would be stripping off more than milliseconds.  *semantically* you want to round the datetime.

Comment: Thank you. Good point. Rounding would indeed be better than just truncating. So perhaps *round* the string in *norok2* answer?